# Rails collection render optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I've been trying to optimize my `render` call, because my ruby code is clearly the slowest part of my site. I've already optimized against N+1 issues.

I've tried this a number of ways.

The first:

```
- @listings.each do |l|
  = render 'listing/show', :listing => l
```

This seems to be the fastest so far, but its still 2 second request for only 20 records!

I've also tried

```
= render :partial => 'listings/listing', :collection => @listings
```

My partial is basically just a consumer-goods listing with a few key pieces of data. Can anyone point me to the official way to optimize this?

Comment: What about `=render @listings`

Comment: I tried that, it's way worse...

Comment: Maybe you could make a workaround with caching? See more about that here: http://ninjasandrobots.com/rails-faster-partial-rendering-and-caching - the guy wrote a gem, which should render and chache faster.

Comment: Yes, thats the working solution right now. You should write this out as an answer for others